# header with logo on first page only of documentclass article

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am writing an article with a header on the first page only; the header includes a logo. Here is a MWE using fancyhdr:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{plain}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[L]{
  \large \textsf{Address line 1\\
    Address line 2\\
    Address line 3}}

\fancyhead[R]{\raisebox{-0.4\height}{
    \includegraphics[width=32mm]{example-image-a}}}

\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\setlength\headheight{68.3pt}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% \title{\flushleft{This is the title}}
% \date{}

\begin{document}
% \maketitle

\section*{A section}

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

With this approach, the text on page 2 starts below where the header would be if it were included on this page.

How do I get the text to start at the "top" of page 2 instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't consider the content at the top of page 1 as being a header. Instead, set it as part of a regular document. That way you don't have to worry about influencing the header space (or `\headheight`) and how it may affect subsequent pages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
  \large\sffamily Address line 1 \\
  \large\sffamily Address line 2 \\
  \large\sffamily Address line 3
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\raisebox{\dimexpr.8\baselineskip-\height}{\includegraphics[width=32mm]{example-image}}

\section*{A section}
\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

The above solution is independent of [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) or [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry), so you can add that without affecting the resulting output/layout.

Answer (score 2):

A simple patch could be the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\fancypagestyle{fancylogo}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[L]{xxx%
        \parbox[t][0pt][t]{.6\textwidth}{%
            \large \textsf{%
                Address line 1\\%
                Address line 2\\%
                Address line 3%
            }%
        }%
    }%
    \fancyhead[R]{%
        \parbox[b][0pt][t]{.3\textwidth}{%
            \vspace{-1cm}% adjust as needed
            \includegraphics[width=32mm]{image-a}%
        }%
    }%
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}



\begin{document}

\vspace*{24pt} % or whatever is needed

\section*{A section}
\thispagestyle{fancylogo}
\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

A neater solution could make use of the `geometry` package to change the page layout of the first page, but for a simple situation like this I think it would be overkill.